# How to cassandra merge snapshots replication factor from 3 to 1

Tags: merge, cassandra, snapshot

Factor 3 cassandra's snapshots need 3 times more space.

I copy snapshots other server for backup, so want reduce size.

Is merge snapshots to actual size possible?

Answer (score 2):

Snapshots are hardlinks of Cassandra sstables files on server level. So merging these files isn't possible, at in least ion easy way.

To save your storage, and save only one "copy" of data, you can try one of these:

1. Export your data to csv, using COPY command.
2. Create additional, "backup" datacenter to you cluster, to which all data will be replicated, with replication factor of 1, and do snapshots there.